# Why does signtool in command-prompt return "Windows cannot find 'signtool'. Make sure you typed the name correctly..."

Tags: sdk, cmd, assembly-signing, signtool

I do have that file. (In "...\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs..."). And I went to installed-programs (in Control Panel) and "reinstalled" it.

So why doesn't the command prompt recognize it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the folder isn't in the system `PATH`. (From the command prompt, type `PATH` and hit enter to see what the current PATH contains.)

You can add the folder by adding the folder to the existing `PATH` from the command prompt (of course, replace the folder with the proper location for the SDK version and location on your system):

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin";%PATH%
```

Signtool should work now from any folder (until you close the command prompt).

You can also create a batch file that sets the `PATH` properly for you to save typing, if you need it often:

```
; Save this as something like SDKEnv.bat in a folder on the current PATH
@SET FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
@SET PATH=%FrameworkDir%;%PATH%
```

Now you can run the batch file just before running SignTool:

```
SDKEnv
Signtool <parameters>
```

Comment: For Windows 8.1 SDK make sure the following is added to your Path. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64;

Comment: @David, Thanks for the 8.1 SDK tip! I couldn't find it after it was moved.

Comment: windows 7 and vs2013 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\signtool.exe

Comment: On Windows10, with a hint from @DavidDouglas, I found it at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64`